# Issue while creating Nested TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am try to implement the Nested TableLayoutPanel. I am try to dynamically Create/load the child TableLayoutPanel inside parent TableLayoutPanel.
for this I take the parent TableLayoutPanel and draw it from visual studio toolbox.
one DropDownList for dynamically to create child TableLayoutPanel I assign some values to dropdownlist such as 2*2,2*3,3*3,4*4 when the selected index change is fire is draws the child TableLayoutPanel.
My code is below

```
private void cmbRowsColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  var selectedPair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
  selectedPair = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)cmbRowsColumns.SelectedItem;
  string[] rowcolumn = selectedPair.Value.Split('*');
  string strRowCount = rowcolumn[0];
  int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(strRowCount);
  string strColumnCount = rowcolumn[1];
  int columnCount = Convert.ToInt32(strColumnCount);
  DynamicallyGenerateColumn(rowCount, columnCount);
}


private void DynamicallyGenerateColumn(int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
  parentTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();
  parentTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
  parentTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
  parentTableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = columnCount;
  parentTableLayoutPanel.RowCount = rowCount;
  for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
      parentTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
      for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
        {
        if (i == 0)
         {
          parentTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
         }
          TableLayoutPanel objTableLayoutPanel = new  TableLayoutPanel();                  
          parentTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(objTableLayoutPanel, i, j);
       }
     }
 }
```

[image]
but actually problem is when I create child TableLayoutPanel the formatting is not properly

Comment: what is not proper? you cant see any child panels or they are in wrong number?

Comment: @Bolu I want to display child TableLayoutPanel inside the Parent TableLayoutPanel properly well formatted.

Comment: What is the result you are getting at the moment with the code above?

Comment: this kind of problem should need some screen shot to describe.

Comment: @KingKing I added the screen shot for getting more clear idea

Comment: @Bolu please check the result i upload thro' screen shot...

Comment: @Bolu the alignment of child TableLayoutPanel isn't proper

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to fill each child panels So you need to add `objTableLayoutPanel.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;`

```
TableLayoutPanel objTableLayoutPanel = new  TableLayoutPanel(); 
objTableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
parentTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(objTableLayoutPanel, i, j);
```

Comment: the alignment of child TableLayoutPanel isn't proper

Comment: Make sure you don't have other settings overwrite the `DockStyle` like `Anchor`....  So move `objTableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` just above `parentTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(objTableLayoutPanel, i, j);` (make sure no other codes in between, and no other settings of `objTableLayoutPanel` after its been added to the `parentTableLayoutPanel`) and try

Comment: as per your code snippets i tried to change code but its not work